# configMap can't create haproxy configuration file in openshift origin pod

Tags: haproxy, openshift-origin

I got an openshift cluster with 2 nodes (a master and a slave), I want to change the config file of my HAproxy router, so i choose to do a configmap.
After i follow this tuto: https://docs.openshift.org/latest/install_config/install/deploy_router.html

the configmap is created, but the pod doesnt want to restart, i got this error:

> I0830 12:35:37.112924       1 router.go:161] Router is including routes in all >namespaces
>   E0830 12:35:37.372029       1 ratelimiter.go:50] error reloading router: exit >status 1
>   [ALERT] 242/123537 (28) : [/usr/sbin/haproxy.main()] No enabled listener found >(check the  keywords) ! Exiting.

After i deleate the "livenessProb" and "readenesProb" in the rc I can access my router pod, but the configfile is empty.
When i do "findmnt -o +PROPAGATION" in the pod i got this :

```
TARGET                           SOURCE               FSTYPE OPTIONS      PROPAGATION
/                                /dev/mapper/docker-253:0-202065893-       4b0b4dede29e355551067e03212ee75cd293545839a9e5014525b8fc8453e5e4[/rootfs]
                                                  xfs    rw,relat private
|-/proc                          proc                 proc   rw,nosui private
| |-/proc/bus                    proc[/bus]           proc   ro,nosui private
| |-/proc/fs                     proc[/fs]            proc   ro,nosui private
| |-/proc/irq                    proc[/irq]           proc   ro,nosui private
| |-/proc/sys                    proc[/sys]           proc   ro,nosui private
| |-/proc/sysrq-trigger          proc[/sysrq-trigger] proc   ro,nosui private
| |-/proc/kcore                  tmpfs[/null]         tmpfs  rw,nosui private
| `-/proc/timer_stats            tmpfs[/null]         tmpfs  rw,nosui private
|-/dev                           tmpfs                tmpfs  rw,nosui private
| |-/dev/pts                     devpts               devpts rw,nosui private
| |-/dev/mqueue                  mqueue               mqueue rw,nosui private
| |-/dev/termination-log         /dev/mapper/centos-    root[/var/lib/origin/openshift.local.volumes/pods/3deedc57-6eae-11e6-8091-   020000a17bb0/containers/router/58cbfd4d]
                                                      xfs    rw,relat   private,slave
| `-/dev/shm                     shm                  tmpfs  rw,nosui   private
|-/sys                           sysfs                sysfs  ro,nosui private
| `-/sys/fs/cgroup               tmpfs                tmpfs  ro,nosui private
|   |-/sys/fs/cgroup/systemd     cgroup[/system.slice/docker-297a37b2903e3a3bcd64d74a4e0c8e71d90cf240377bbc4b778e73ebda53af0c.scope]
                                                  cgroup ro,nosui  private,slave
|   |-/sys/fs/cgroup/cpuacct,cpu cgroup[/system.slice/docker-297a37b2903e3a3bcd64d74a4e0c8e71d90cf240377bbc4b778e73ebda53af0c.scope]
                                                      cgroup ro,nosui private,slave
|   |-/sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset      cgroup[/system.slice/docker-297a37b2903e3a3bcd64d74a4e0c8e71d90cf240377bbc4b778e73ebda53af0c.scope]
                                                      cgroup ro,nosui  private,slave
|   |-/sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls     cgroup[/system.slice/docker-297a37b2903e3a3bcd64d74a4e0c8e71d90cf240377bbc4b778e73ebda53af0c.scope]
                                                  cgroup ro,nosui private,slave
|   |-/sys/fs/cgroup/memory      cgroup[/system.slice/docker-297a37b2903e3a3bcd64d74a4e0c8e71d90cf240377bbc4b778e73ebda53af0c.scope]
                                                  cgroup ro,nosui private,slave
|   |-/sys/fs/cgroup/blkio       cgroup[/system.slice/docker-297a37b2903e3a3bcd64d74a4e0c8e71d90cf240377bbc4b778e73ebda53af0c.scope]
                                                  cgroup ro,nosui private,slave
|   |-/sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event  cgroup[/system.slice/docker-297a37b2903e3a3bcd64d74a4e0c8e71d90cf240377bbc4b778e73ebda53af0c.scope]
                                                  cgroup ro,nosui private,slave
|   |-/sys/fs/cgroup/devices     cgroup[/system.slice/docker-297a37b2903e3a3bcd64d74a4e0c8e71d90cf240377bbc4b778e73ebda53af0c.scope]
                                                  cgroup ro,nosui private,slave
|   |-/sys/fs/cgroup/freezer     cgroup[/system.slice/docker-297a37b2903e3a3bcd64d74a4e0c8e71d90cf240377bbc4b778e73ebda53af0c.scope]
                                                  cgroup ro,nosui private,slave
|   `-/sys/fs/cgroup/hugetlb     cgroup[/system.slice/docker-297a37b2903e3a3bcd64d74a4e0c8e71d90cf240377bbc4b778e73ebda53af0c.scope]
                                                  cgroup ro,nosui private,slave
|-/run/secrets                   /dev/mapper/centos-  root[/var/lib/docker/containers/297a37b2903e3a3bcd64d74a4e0c8e71d90cf240377bbc4b778e73ebda53af0c/secrets]
                                                  xfs    rw,relat private,slave
| `-/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount
                             tmpfs                tmpfs  ro,relat private,slave
|-/etc/hosts                     /dev/mapper/centos-root[/var/lib/docker/containers/56f5ea1e5e2fb9392b9cb3cfc6eecc43d42eb23f9769793e6b2e4f7250c7cf5c/hosts]
                                                  xfs    rw,relat private
|-/etc/resolv.conf               /dev/mapper/centos-root[/var/lib/docker/containers/56f5ea1e5e2fb9392b9cb3cfc6eecc43d42eb23f9769793e6b2e4f7250c7cf5c/resolv.conf]
                                                  xfs    rw,relat private
|-/etc/hostname                  /dev/mapper/centos-root[/var/lib/docker/containers/56f5ea1e5e2fb9392b9cb3cfc6eecc43d42eb23f9769793e6b2e4f7250c7cf5c/hostname]
                                                  xfs    rw,relat private
`-/var/lib/haproxy/conf/custom   tmpfs                tmpfs  rw,relat private,slave
```

Any help ? Thanks

Comment: It's possible the location you mounted the config map into isn't correct.  Double check that it is the location that the haproxy --conf argument (in the pod definition) is pointing to.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a template file for the openshift router.

This explains in detail what you need to do.

https://docs.openshift.org/latest/install_config/install/deploy_router.html#using-configmap-replace-template